# WCF Message Inspector error with Kerberos Authentication

Tags: c#, wcf

I've got a WCF Service host and preconfigured message inspector to validate messages by XSD schema and overall message size. Here is its implementation.

```
public class SimpleMessageInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
{
    private AsyncAPISender _messageSender = new AsyncAPISender();
    private ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(SimpleMessageInspector));
    private readonly XmlSchemaSet _schemas;
    // Max packet syze 50 Mb by default
    private const int MaxPacketSizeByDefault = 52428800;

    //Other methods of IDispatchMessageInspector

    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        logger.DebugFormat("Recieved SOAP message: {0}", request);

        var mb = request.CreateBufferedCopy(int.MaxValue);

        request = mb.CreateMessage();
        var copyForValidation = mb.CreateMessage();
        var copyForCheckSize = mb.CreateMessage();

        ValidateMessage(ref copyForValidation);

        CheckMessageSize(mb, ref copyForCheckSize);

        return null;
    }

    void ValidateMessage(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message message)
    {
        XmlDocument bodyDoc = new XmlDocument();
        bodyDoc.Load(message.GetReaderAtBodyContents().ReadSubtree());
        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.Schemas.Add(_schemas);
        settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
        XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create(new XmlNodeReader(bodyDoc), settings);

        try
        {
            while (r.Read()) { }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Error on validation by xsd schema", e);
        }
    }

    private void CheckMessageSize(MessageBuffer buffer, ref Message message)
    {
        int maxPacketSize;
        var maxPacketSizeFromConfig = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaxPacketSize"];
        if (!Int32.TryParse(maxPacketSizeFromConfig, out maxPacketSize))
        {
            maxPacketSize = MaxPacketSizeByDefault;
        }

        if (buffer.BufferSize > maxPacketSize)
        {
            var messageInfo = GetMessageInfoType(ref message);
            if (messageInfo != null)
                _messageSender.CreateResultTask(messageInfo, null, "Max message size exceeded", false);

            throw new Exception("Max message size exceeded");
        }
    }
}
```

When host recieves message I've got an exception "This message cannot support the operation because it has been read" It only heppens when host uses Kerberos binding with basicHttp everything is ok. Here is the binding config which causes an error.

```
<binding name="customKerberosBinding">
  <security authenticationMode="Kerberos" allowInsecureTransport="true" enableUnsecuredResponse="false" requireDerivedKeys="false" protectTokens="false" requireSignatureConfirmation="false" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12BasicSecurityProfile10"></security>
  <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11"></textMessageEncoding>
            <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000000"></httpTransport>
</binding>
```

Is there any explanations why is happening only on kerberos binding and possible solutions?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with using `IDispatchMessageInspector` is that you can only read the message once. Since your reading it and it is being passed by reference I think that is why you are getting this error. In my ValidateMessage method after I do my validation, I create a copy of the message and return it.

```
object IDispatchMessageInspector.AfterReceiveRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel, System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext instanceContext)
{
    if (validateRequest)
    {
        if (!request.IsEmpty && !request.IsFault)
        {
            request = ValidateRequestMessageBody(request);
            channel.Close();
            channel.Dispose();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private Message ValidateRequestMessageBody(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message message)
{
    //do stuff
    var reader = XmlReader.Create(memStream, settings);                        
    var newMessage = Message.CreateMessage(reader, int.MaxValue, message.Version);
    newMessage.Headers.Clear();
    newMessage.Headers.CopyHeadersFrom(message.Headers);
    return newMessage;
}
```